# Para que serve a keyword debugger em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Estava navegando pela documentação do [ECMAScript](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1) e me deparei com a sessão de *keywords reservadas*

Segue:

> The following tokens are ECMAScript keywords and may not be used as
>   Identifiers in ECMAScript programs.
>
> Keyword :: one of

`break  do  instanceof  typeof case else    new var`

`catch  finally return  void continue   for switch  while`

**debugger** `function  this    with default    if  throw    delete in  try`

---

Todas essas keywords eu conheço, e uso, umas com mais frequência, outras com menos, porem ate hoje nunca tinha visto essa: debugger.

Tentei aplicar um exemplo dessa keyword no jsfiddle mas não entendi o seu funcionamento.
Para que ela existe? Qual sua utilidade? E quando usar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É equivalente ao `breakpoint` de outras linguagens, ele pausa a execução do script e **só funciona** se *Developer tools* do navegador ou outro depurador (como no Node.js) estiver aberto, se não estiver aberto não terá efeito.

Por exemplo, execute o Snippet abaixo e abra o Developer tools, depois clique em testar:

```js
function a() {}
function b() {}

function foo() {
    a();
    debugger;
    b();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="foo();">Executar</button>
```

No Chrome/Opera vai aparecer algo como:

[image: breakpoint]

Note que tem *Paused in debugger*, se clicar no botão play ele vai continuar até encontrar outro `debugger;`

> Na maior parte dos navegadores para usar o play pode apertar o <kbd>F8</kbd>

### Como usar

Claro que no exemplo que fiz acima não tem muito sentido usa-lo, a ideia de usar breakpoint e o debugger é você usa-lo em vários lugares e analisar aonde ocorre o erro, por exemplo:

```
function foo() {
    a();

    debugger;

    b();

    debugger;

    c();

    debugger;

    d();

    debugger;

    code code code...
    code code code...
    code code code...

    debugger;

    code code code...

    debugger;
}
```

Imagine que você tem várias bibliotecas ou um script enorme do qual você não está entendendo aonde está o problema, ou não sabe aonde o problema começou, por exemplo uma variável manipulada por vários scripts e funções está chegando com `null`, então você pode manualmente aplicar vários `debugger;` combinados a `console` e testando passo a passo o que ocorre com a variável

Depurar não tem haver diretamente com ambientes visuais, tem haver com analisar as saídas e retornos de códigos e o debugger/breakpoint é apenas para "pausar" e você poder testar.

Por exemplo (claro que você pode usar o debugger em qualquer lugar do teu script):

```
function foo() {
    x = a();

    console.log(x);
    debugger;

    b(x);

    console.log(x);
    debugger;

    c(x);

    console.log(x);
    debugger;

    d(x);

    console.log(x);
    debugger;

    code code code...
    code code code...
    x = code code code...

    console.log(x);
    debugger;
}
```

Se estiver em uma navegador você e tiver problema com alguma manipulação do DOM, você colocar o debugger em vários lugares e a cada debugger analisar o DOM pela aba `Elements`.

Comment: E depois dar um `F8` para continuar a execução (no navegador, pelo menos), senão fica travado no *breakpoint*.

Comment: eu cheguei a tentar usar o debugger para testar se o developer tools estava aberto if(debugger){alert()} kkkk

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não sei se F8 é padrão em todos sistema e navegadores, mas obrigado pela dica +1